# Segmentation Fault while copying unsigned int values in C

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, pointers, segmentation-fault

Hi I try to copy Counter64 type for SNMP Get function I get seg fault. Now I wrote a normal C function and compiled using gcc in LINUX I got this error

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

I am running in UBUNTU 64 bit PC. Please Help to solve this error.
My code is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct SNMP_COUNTER64_TYPE {
    unsigned int  msn;
    unsigned int  lsn;
} tSNMP_COUNTER64_TYPE;

int main (void)
{
    unsigned int a = 50;
    unsigned int b = 20;

    tSNMP_COUNTER64_TYPE *pu8RetVal;
    memset(pu8RetVal, 0, sizeof(tSNMP_COUNTER64_TYPE));

    pu8RetVal->msn = a;
    pu8RetVal->lsn = b;

    printf("\n\t%d.%d\n", pu8RetVal->msn, pu8RetVal->lsn);
}
```

Comment: I used the same code provided. NO segmentation fault for me.

Comment: @MukeshVerma That is the beauty of undefined behavior.

Comment: Are you, by happenstance, working for [Nortel](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=18447313)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `pu8RetVal` does not point to any *valid* memory. Being an automatic local scoped variable, the initial content of `pu8RetVal` is indeterminate - thus you are using the invalid memory which leads to [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Before you can read to write to the address pointed by any pointer, you need to make sure that the pointer points to some valid memory.

One way of doing that would be, change `pu8RetVal` from a pointer to structure to a structure type variable, something like

```
tSNMP_COUNTER64_TYPE pu8RetVal;
```

and change the indirection operators accordingly. You would need to pass the address of the variable to `memset()`, obviously.

Comment: NO segmentation fault for me for same piece of code provided.

Comment: @MukeshVerma Please read about the linked article in the answer,

Comment: No dude I need to use Pointer its standard for snmpget function pu8RetVal is the return variable.

Comment: @Aravind OK, then, make sure you point your pointer to valid value. Either assign the address of another `pu8RetVal` variable, or use `malloc()` to allocate memory.